# iOS, UIPickerView - no bounce

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Programmatically, how would one disable the bounce effect for a `UIPickerView` when scrolling in iOS?

Comment: Which bounce effect? When you reach the end? What's the option in storyboard?

Comment: I'm using iOS simulator however i assume it is the same with a real device. When i scroll up or down on the picker, i can drag nearly twice the distance of the total rows, how would i make it so the bounds of the drag/scroll gesture are limited to the height of the total rows? (i also mistook the tableview bounce option in storyboard- my mistake)

Comment: I think no way to do disable the bounce effect.